# Tensorboard not displaying event files

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have an issue where I am training a model, but tensorboard isn't displaying any data from the event files. I've done everything in my knowledge. Yes I read the tensorboard ReadMe FAQ. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/README.md#frequently-asked-questions

I start the train process with the folowing command (cmd started in folder with the directories "tf_files" and "flower_photos" in it):

`python retrain.py --bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks --model_dir=tf_files/models/"mobilenet_0.50_224" --summaries_dir=tf_files/training_summaries/"mobilenet_0.50_224" --output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb --output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt --architecture="mobilenet_0.50_224" --image_dir=flower_photos`

https://www.mediafire.com/view/22orxlkdfleiw4u/retrain_start_1.png

https://www.mediafire.com/file/hfexqjci64o6aqw/retrain_start_2.png

https://www.mediafire.com/view/3uzfyvz4hqj44wh/retrain_finish.png

The retraining finishes successfully.

Tensorboard i start with the command:

`tensorboard --logdir i:/temp/learningtf/tf_files/training_summaries`

https://www.mediafire.com/view/j366d29whwrdbwz/start_tensorboard.png

The command above with `--inspect` give me the following output:

https://www.mediafire.com/view/3s0x11zb61b8si8/tensorboard_inspect_1.png

https://www.mediafire.com/view/45k87w8h15b48ks/tensorboard_inspect_2.png

As you can see, tensorboard doesn't display anything. Im quite confused.

https://www.mediafire.com/view/v74qashzjq0wnxr/tensorboard_webinterface.png

Here are the event files I'm talking about. If these are not the files you need, post a reply and tell my which files i need to upload, please.
[the_i_hope_right_files.zip](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/files/1412114/the_i_hope_right_files.zip)

If you need eny further Info on this case, please let me know.
Thanks for any help in advance.